# Why does the worker service template not gracefully shut down as systemd?

Tags: c#, .net-core, systemd, background-service

I created a new project using the worker service template and added two lines.

One extra log output in the worker after being stopped:

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker stopped."); // <---- extra log output
    }
```

And one in the Program.cs for systemd support:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSystemd() // <---- systemd support
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

I can start and stop the service on my ubuntu server, but in the journalctl output the extra log line does not appear:

```
worker[25468]: WorkerService.Worker[0] Worker running at: 02/10/2021 23:07:34 +01:00
systemd[1]: Stopping Long running service/daemon created from .NET worker template...
worker[25468]: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Application is shutting down...
// here I would expect "Worker stopped."
systemd[1]: Stopped Long running service/daemon created from .NET worker template.
```

How can I make sure that my background service runs to completion before the service stops?

I have found this very similar question, unfortunately it has no satisfying answer:
[.NET core BackgroundService does not shut down gracefully as daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936664/net-core-backgroundservice-does-not-shut-down-gracefully-as-daemon)

But I can't believe there isn't a simple answer to this.

**UPDATE:**

I found a way to gracefully shut down the service.
Instead of waiting for the `stoppingToken` in the `ExecuteAsync()` to be triggered, I am checking a flag, whether the service should stop running, which is set in the `StopAsync()` method. Using a `ManualResetEvent` I can then decide, if the service should wait for the Backgroundservice to finish its work and shut down gracefully, or if it should force a shut down after a given timeout.
This is probably not the most elegant way to do it, but it seems to do what I want.

```
    private bool _stopRunning;
    private ManualResetEvent _mre;
    private int _graceperiod = 5000;
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _stopRunning = false;
        _mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        int item = 1;
        while (!_stopRunning)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Working on item " + item);
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            _logger.LogInformation("still working on item " + item);
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            _logger.LogInformation("Finished working on item " + item);
            item++;
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("Worker stopped.");
        _mre.Set();
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _stopRunning = true;
        bool gracefulShutdown = _mre.WaitOne(_graceperiod);
        if (gracefulShutdown)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Shut down service gracefully");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Force shut down service");
        }
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

I still would like to understand though, how the stoppingToken is supposed to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can ovveride `StopAsync` method of `BackgroundService` class. Like this

```
public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // add your logging or anything extra here
    return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: I have experimented with the StopAsync() function. But as soon as base.StopAsync() is called, the service shuts down ungracefully. I would like to trigger the stoppingToken in the ExecuteAsync() somehow, but I don't understand the underlying mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

An exception is thrown (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.). Use something like this to see it:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"ExecuteAsync() started, stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested: {stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested}");
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, $"ExecuteAsync() exception, stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested: {stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested}");
    }
    finally
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"ExecuteAsync() stopped, stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested: {stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested}");
    }
}
```